A question for the Rolling Cross Validation where the tsCV function in R is used
I have one data set consisting of a total of 16 data (quarterly data from 2012 to 2015) as sample data set.
I want to predict the 15th data (3rd quarter of 2015) from the model learned with an arima model using the data up to the 14th (2nd quarter of 2015), and then calculate the difference(=error) from the 15th actual data. However, the 15th (3rd quarter of 2015) error value (actual value - predicted value) calculated by the first method mentioned in the coding below was output at the 14th (2nd quarter of 2015) position in the second method where the tsCV function is used. Can someone please explain about this?
library(forecast)
### First method
tscv_test1 <- c(11, 25, 3, 8, 7, 78, 5, 2, 7, 82, 20, 10, 22, 45, 11, 8)
tscv_test1_ts <- ts(tscv_test1, start= c(2012, 1), freq = 4) 
train.length = 14
train.ts1 <- window(tscv_test1_ts, start=c(2012,1), end=c(2012, train.length))
valid.ts1 <- window(tscv_test1_ts, start=c(2012, train.length+1), end=c(2012, train.length+1))
arima.fit1 <- arima(train.ts1, order=c(0,0,0), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,0), period=4))
arima.pred1 <- forecast(arima.fit1, h= 1)
error1 <- valid.ts1 - arima.pred1$mean[1]
error1
### Second method
tscv_test1_cv <- window(x = tscv_test1_ts, start=c(2012,1), end=c(2015,4))
far2 <- function(x, h){forecast(arima(x, order=c(0,0,0), seasonal=list(order=c(0,1,0), period=4)), h=h)}
error_test1 <- tsCV(tscv_test1_cv, far2, h=1)
error_test1


Please read the help function help(tsCV):

Value: Numerical time series object containing the forecast errors as a vector (if h=1) and a matrix otherwise. The time index corresponds to the last period of the training data. The columns correspond to the forecast horizons.


I understood that the 15th error value appeared at the 14th position because the 14th data was the data of the last period used for the training data.
Thanks for your explanation.
